# title not displaying correctly Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having a problem with my website (http://nts.nuvisiontechs.co.za/).
I have a section for which the title is supposed to change when I click on the different buttons (Contact Us on the menu, Book an Appointment and Book a Consultation on the page). The jQuery code is working for the 2 last ones but not for the "Contact Us" button : 
if I click on "Book an appointment" and then on "Contact Us", it's the title "Book an appointment that is displayed, instead of "Contact Us".

Here is my jQuery code :

```
$('#bookappointment').click(function(){
    $('#titleContent').text("Book an Appointment");
});

$('#bookconsultation').click(function(){
    $('#titleContent').text("Book a Consultation"); 
});

$('#contactbtn').click(function(){
    $('#titleContent').text("Contact Us");  
});
```

Here are my buttons :

```
<a id="contactbtn" class="button secondary-button" href="http://nts.nuvisiontechs.co.za/#contactus"> 
    Contact Us
</a>

<p style="text-align: right;">
    <a id="bookappointment" class="button secondary-button" style="text-align: center;" href="http://nts.nuvisiontechs.co.za/#contactus">
        Book an appointment
    </a>
</p>

<p style="text-align: center;">
    <a id="bookconsultation" class="button secondary-button" style="text-align: left;" href="http://nts.nuvisiontechs.co.za/#contactus">
        Book a Consultation
    </a>
</p>
```

I have no idea what to do because this code is actually working for the 2 others. Does somebody has an idea ?

Comment: The problem is because you have two elements with the same id in your HTML - both called `contactbtn`.

Comment: Where is the second one ? Because I changed the name yesterday from contactbutton to contactbtn to check that.

Comment: It may be duplicate content generated by a plugin you're using for the fixed header. Check this image: http://i.imgur.com/3goHta2.png

Comment: It works ! Thank you so much for your help :)